# Microstack commandline api not working

Tags: openstack

Unable to use the commandline for any user, after sourcing user-openrc.sh.

Most likely microstack init did not configure it properly.

I am getting the following response in every command:

```
microstack.openstack flavor list
The request you have made requires authentication. (HTTP 401) (Request-ID: req-44be8ba3-38bb-4c48-b1dd-548d5a2afee0)
```

openrc exports OS_AUTH_URL=http://10.20.20.1:5000/v3/

but /snap/microstack/current/etc/glance/glance-api.conf does not set auth_url or any other parameters.

Comment: I had the very same problem with Microstack Stein. Microstack Ussuri fixed it, but does not restart or reboot properly, so it is useless to me.

Answer (score 0):

I found I had to add `--os-user` and `--os-password` to all calls to microstack.openstack. Setting the environment didn't work (is it not available to the snap?). Did you find another way around?